# The pre-application start initialization method Start on type PreApplicationStartCode threw an exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, webmatrix

I have created a new WebMatrix-based website in Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate and added DB First EF ADO.NET to the site.

I have WebPages 3 installed, and .NET Framework is 4.5.

However, when I try to debug/Build the solution, it throws this error:

> Error 1   The pre-application start initialization method Start on type
>   System.Web.WebPages.Administration.PreApplicationStartCode threw an
>   exception with the following error message: Attempt by security
>   transparent method
>   'System.Web.WebPages.Administration.SiteAdmin.RegisterAdminModule()'
>   to access security critical method
>   'System.Web.WebPages.ApplicationPart..ctor(System.Reflection.Assembly,
>   System.String)' failed..

The only result that appears for this error in Google is http://craigwilson.id.au/2014/03/18/azurewap-system-methodaccessexception-attempt-by-security-transparent-method/#comment-1308 however, the solution on that page is to install WebHelpers via Package Manager console. This solution did *not* fix it for me.

Why am I getting this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25775234/methodaccessexception-inside-system-web-webpages-migrating-mvc-3-to-mvc-5

Comment: @e4rthdog's comment should be an answer, not just a comment.  Thanks for providing the solution I needed!