# MethodAccessException inside System.Web.WebPages migrating mvc 3 to mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Using Visual Studio 2013, I migrated a hybrid Asp.Net Webforms/MVC 3/Framework 4.0 web application to Asp.Net Webforms/MVC 5.2.2/Framework 4.5.1.

I followed the steps outlined in these links:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/upgrading-signalr-1x-projects-to-20

When I run the application in visual studio I get this error:

> Attempt by security transparent method
>   'System.Web.WebPages.Administration.SiteAdmin.RegisterAdminModule()'
>   to access security critical method
>   'System.Web.WebPages.ApplicationPart..ctor(System.Reflection.Assembly,
>   System.String)' failed.

I have tried these suggestions that I found on StackOverflow, but none fix the problem:

1. clear the bin folder and rebuild
2. Install Nuget package Microsoft.Aspnet.WebHelpers.
3. Make sure all web.config references of System.Web.Mvc and System.Web.WebPages point to the correct version (5.2.2.0 and 3.0.0.0 respectively).

Any advice on how to find the cause of this error would be much appreciated.

The full stack trace of the error:

```
[MethodAccessException: Attempt by security transparent method 'System.Web.WebPages.Administration.SiteAdmin.RegisterAdminModule()' to access security critical method 'System.Web.WebPages.ApplicationPart..ctor(System.Reflection.Assembly, System.String)' failed.]
   System.Web.WebPages.Administration.SiteAdmin.RegisterAdminModule() +96
   System.Web.WebPages.Administration.PreApplicationStartCode.Start() +41

[InvalidOperationException: The pre-application start initialization method Start on type System.Web.WebPages.Administration.PreApplicationStartCode threw an exception with the following error message: Attempt by security transparent method 'System.Web.WebPages.Administration.SiteAdmin.RegisterAdminModule()' to access security critical method 'System.Web.WebPages.ApplicationPart..ctor(System.Reflection.Assembly, System.String)' failed..]
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethodsCore(ICollection`1 methods, Func`1 setHostingEnvironmentCultures) +559
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethods(ICollection`1 methods) +132
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) +102
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +153
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +516

[HttpException (0x80004005): The pre-application start initialization method Start on type System.Web.WebPages.Administration.PreApplicationStartCode threw an exception with the following error message: Attempt by security transparent method 'System.Web.WebPages.Administration.SiteAdmin.RegisterAdminModule()' to access security critical method 'System.Web.WebPages.ApplicationPart..ctor(System.Reflection.Assembly, System.String)' failed..]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9913572
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +101
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +254
```

Comment: Have you tried installing Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.Data package?

Comment: Yes, the Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.Data package is installed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem was that the web application had a reference to a (Framework 1) version of System.Web.Administration.dll, I assume because this reference was needed a couple of years ago when the application moved from web forms to hybrid webforms/MVC 3.

I removed this reference and the problem disappeared.  Apparently this dll is no longer used. I assume the runtime was fetching the conflicting version of System.Web.Administration from this dll instead of using the new version.

Comment: how did you remove the reference?

Comment: @e4rthdog, expand the "References" node in the solution explorer, find System.Web.Administration.dll, right-click it, select "remove"

Comment: I had approximately the same error, and the reference I had to remove was System.Web.WebPages.Administration.  Note that it's ".WebPages." which is different than above.

Comment: Could a different DLL be causing the same error? I have the same error after being forced to update dependencies, but I can't find the culprit. How would you go about finding the framework mismatch?

Comment: @pate, is there a *.dll cited in the error message?  If not, you might try removing all references, then adding them back one-by-one and do that via Nuget packages to make updates easier in the future.

Comment: `System.Web.WebPages.Administration.dll` was the culprit. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

I was getting the same error on Asp.Net Webforms/MVC 5.2.2/Framework 4.5.1. when I published to Azure (it was working fine on localhost).

The solution, obtained from http://craigwilson.id.au/2014/03/18/azurewap-system-methodaccessexception-attempt-by-security-transparent-method/ was:

1. Install the package Microsoft.AspNet.WebHelpers. From the Package management console run the following command:

   Install-Package -Id  Microsoft.AspNet.WebHelpers
2. Check the deployment option "Remove additional files at destination" located at *Publish... -> Settings -> File Publish Options*.

Comment: "Remove additional files at destination" was what was causing a problem for me.  I presume there were some older DLLs in the default Azure ASP.NET Web App that needed to be removed.

Answer (score 2):

When I had this problem I also had to delete the contents of the obj folder.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but deleting the obj folder does not fix it.  I've deleted obj, bin and also the framework Temporary ASP.net files, and even tried rebooting.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a new web site from a template and was getting this error when web site was published to Azure. I've checked "remove extra files" and "precompile" which are unchecked by default and it helped. I didn't try any other options.